How does Typescript handle "as const" type
I have been looking at this piece of code for some time and I am not sure why Typescript complains about it

const UserStatus = {
  gaming: 'gaming',
  sleeping: 'sleeping',
  reading: 'reading',
  movie: 'movies',
  idle: 'idle',
} as const;

type UserStatus = keyof typeof UserStatus;

const u: {name: string, s: UserStatus} = {name: "Joe", s: UserStatus.gaming};

const i = [UserStatus.sleeping, UserStatus.idle].includes(u.s);

console.log(i);


Typescript complains about this part .includes(u.s).
Can someone explain what is going on there?

Argument of type '"gaming" | "sleeping" | "reading" | "idle" | "movie"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"sleeping" | "idle"'.
  Type '"gaming"' is not assignable to type '"sleeping" | "idle"'.(2345)
const u: {
    name: string;
    s: UserStatus;
}


• Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions. • See the linked q/a for information about your question
